# PHP5 Using a class within a class

Tags: php, oop

I am trying to use a class within a class, but seem to be having an issue with the initialised content of the class. It can see the class structure fine if you do a var_dump, but it wont see the content you have initialised with. I know im probably missing something pretty obvious, any pointers would be great. An example is below...

```
class firstClass()
{

    public $thedate;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->thedate = date();
    }

}


class secondClass()
{

    public $datefrom1stclass;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->datefrom1stclass = new firstClass;

        echo $this->datefrom1stclass->thedate;

    }

}
```

Sorry if I have not explained very well, If I do a var_dump I get the following:

```
object(firstClass)#3 (1) { ["thedate"]=> NULL }
```

Any pointers would be appreciated!

Comment: Once you fix the syntax errors and pass an argument to `date()`, it works fine: http://codepad.org/kDvuEWR3

Comment: Sorry guys, looks like I missed an 'S' out of __construct for the first class, which is why it wasnt being initialised with anything!!

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't call [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) without any parameters: at least one (a format, as a string) should be given:

```
$this->thedate = date('D M j G:i:s T Y');
```

The rest of your code is correct (although I'd prefer `new firstClass()` form, with parentheses - it's more readable).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct code  :) Enjoy 
`

```
public $thedate;

function __construct()
{
    $this->thedate = date("Ymd");
}
```

}

class secondClass
{

```
public $datefrom1stclass;

function __construct()
{
    $this->datefrom1stclass = new firstClass;

    echo $this->datefrom1stclass->thedate;

}
```

}
$var = new secondClass();
var_dump(  $var );
?>
`